# Expand only one row in javascript code

Tags: javascript

hey guys having trouble figuring out how to make it so that i can make it only open one table at once, once you open another the other should close any help here?

```
function showRow(cctab){
if (document.getElementById(cctab)) {
    document.getElementById(cctab).style.display = ''; 
}
}

function hideRow(row1){
if (document.getElementById(cctab)) {
    document.getElementById(cctab).style.display = 'none';
}
}

function toggleRow(cctab){
if (document.getElementById(cctab)) {
    if (document.getElementById(cctab).style.display == 'none') {
        showRow(cctab)
    } else {
        hideRow(cctab)
    }
}
}
```

Now I want to make it so that only one table "cctab" opens after I suggest the onClick="javascript:toggleRow(cctab);" anyhelp?

Comment: JavaScript is dependant on HTML, can you show us what HTML you're working with, and, perhaps, post a live [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo for us to see your code in action?

Comment: Inline `on*` events are very old and lead to unscalable code. Are you open to a slight code-rewrite, handling the events centrally? If so, post your HTML and we can help.

Comment: Your `hideRow()` function has copy/paste errors. It receives a parameter `row1`, but uses the `cctab` parameter as copied from other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could save a reference to the previously shown item and hide it when another is shown:

```
var currentTab;    
function showRow(cctab){
    if (document.getElementById(cctab))
        document.getElementById(cctab).style.display = '';
    if (currentTab && currentTab != cctab)
        hideRow(currentTab);
    currentTab = cctab;
}
```

Note that doing inline event handler attributes is *so* 1999, but assuming you're sticking with it for whatever reason you don't need the `javascript:` in `onClick="javascript:toggleRow(cctab);"`. (Just say `onClick="toggleRow(cctab);"`)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to store the old row somewhere.
What you've got is a system where you're using `<element onclick="...">` to pass the id of the current element into the controller that shows or hides the row.

But if you look at that, what you're missing is a way of telling what the last open row was.
So what your code will need is a central object, or variables which store the old element and the new element.

How you do this is up to you, but if you did something like this:

```
var table_rows = { current : null /* or set a default */, previous : null };

function rowController (cctab) {
    var newRow = document.getElementById(cctab);

    if (newRow === table_rows.current) { toggleRow(newRow); }
    else {
        table_rows.previous = table_rows.current;
        table_rows.current = newRow;
        showRow(table_rows.current);
        hideRow(table_rows.previous);
    }
}
```

Note:

1. This deals with elements directly, so you don't have to do getById in your functions;
   that's handled one time, and then that element is passed around and saved and checked against.
2. It assumes that the click is happening on the row itself, and not on anything inside of the row;
   that's a separate issue that your code has.
   Unless it's obvious and easy to click on the row, and not the cells inside of the row, it's difficult to tell how you want users to be able to open and close rows.
   What I mean is if only the table-row has an onclick, and somebody clicks on a table-column, then then onclick isn't going to fire.